# How does cin split a sequence of integers?

Tags: c++

How does `cin` split a sequence of integers? An example of this has been given below:

```
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    int sum = 0, value = 0;
    while (std::cin >> value) {
        sum += value;
    }
    std::cout << "Sum is: " << sum << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

So if the input is:
3 10 30 2 5
The output will be:
50

But how does that happen? Are those values treated like an array/list of some kind or is the value of a single variable being changed because of the while loop?

Beginner here.

Comment: What do you mean by "how"? How it's implemented?

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt

Comment: I forgot to add the question. I have edited the original question by adding some stuff. Check it out again. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the extraction from the website http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/basic_io/:

> Extractions on cin can also be chained to request more than one datum
>   in a single statement:
>
> cin >> a >> b;
>
> This is equivalent to:
>
> 1 2
>
> cin >> a; cin >> b;
>
> In both cases, the user is expected to introduce two values, one for
>   variable a, and another for variable b. Any kind of space is used to
>   separate two consecutive input operations; this may either be a space,
>   a tab, or a new-line character.

Comment: Hey Pooya! Thanks! May you check my question again? I forgot to add some stuff. And my current value for cin is stored in one variable. It's kind of confusing. I have edited my original post. Thanks!

Comment: It is treated as a stream of data. cin will consume the stream and finds the data it needs. for getting integers, the cin will look for a separator like space, tab or newline character and parse the data until the separator to find the value of it

Comment: So, all the data? It's stored in one variable all the time? The previous data is deleted? Cool.

Comment: @Superex in each while iteration, value is captured from the input stream and is added to accumulative variable (in this case sum). "value" is considered temporary variable here and "sum" will hold you actual sum value. When "value" is added to "sum" there is no need to keep "value" and it can be overwritten

Comment: I had no idea that "while" could iterate through each and every value of the input. Thanks. My question has been answered.

Comment: I tried to convert the while loop into a for loop. http://cpp.sh/6n67 What happened over here?

Comment: the for loop usually works for some iterative operations where there is a known exit condition. the best for loop you can use here is: for(;cin >> value;). But I think it is unnecessary. Generally for parsing streams, "while" is preffered

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104083/discussion-between-superex-and-pooya).

Answer (score 0):

> How does `cin` split a sequence of integers?

Simple, let's verify some things here..

```
#include <stdio>

using std::cin;
```

First, what is `std::cin`? It is an object created within the standard I\O library included above.

```
cin >> 123 >> "test" >> true;
```

What is `>>` and how does it work? It is a function in `std::cin` class. You are calling a function, how? the above example is equivalent to the following..

```
cin.operator>>(123).operator>>("test").operator>>(true);
```

The trick here, known as [Method Cascading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_cascading), is that the function `cin::operator>>` will return `cin`, so the code will work like this..

```
cin.operator>>(123);
cin.operator>>("test");
cin.operator>>(true);
```